# Textarea in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, view, textarea, response

I have to print the reponse of API in textarea UI (blade.php) in laravel 5.4.

Tried doing:

```
{{ Form::textarea('response', '3 < 4') }}
```

But it gives the following error:

```
 (1/1) FatalErrorException

Class 'Form' not found
```

What can I do to achieve this. In short I want an response textarea like it is in restclient.

Thanks !

Comment: First run this command in cmd: `composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.2.0"`, Add `providers` and `alias` in `config/app.php` file. Then you can use `{{ Form::textarea('response', '3 < 4') }}`

Comment: Try using `\Form`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install `Laravel FormCollective`.

Run the following command from the Terminal: `composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.2.0"`

Next, add your new provider to the providers array of `config/app.php`:

```
'providers' => [
     // ...
     Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
     // ...
 ],
```

Finally, add two class aliases to the aliases array of `config/app.php`:

```
 'aliases' => [
      // ...
      'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
      'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
      // ...
],
```

Then, you can use `{{ Form::textarea('response', '3 < 4') }}` in your blade file!

Hope you understand!

Comment: If this fixed your issue, please close the question with accept my answer!!

Comment: @ShraddhaBanerjee Your welcome! Happy to help you! :)

Answer (score 1):

The Form class is not a part of the default install of Laravel 5.
Please refer to installation here: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html